# Thread already started when re-setting contentView

Tags: java, android

I have this code on my MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      float x = (float)(event.getX());
        float y = (float)(event.getY());
    if(y>=screenh/3&&y<(screenh/4)*2)
        setContentView(g);
```

g is a surfaceview. When I click on this specific place on the screen I want to set the contentview to the surfaceview, but it gives me "thread already started" exception at:

```
    @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                    gameLoopThread.start();
        }
```

if I set the contentview at onCreate to g, there is no error. 
Why?

Answer (score 0):

"Thread already started" because calling setContentView(g) in the onTouchEvent() invokes surfaceCreated(), which leads to an attempt to start the thread again.

You should therefore check the state of the thread before starting it:

```
if (gameLoopThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW){
     gameLoopThread.start();
}
```

Why?

Because, according to the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), once started, a Thread may not be restarted. 
Meaning, you can only call gameLoopThread.start() once on a single instance.

Also make sure you call the resume() and pause() methods of the surface view from the onResume() and onPause() methods of MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        g.resume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        g.pause();
     }
```

Comment: now it doesn't crash, but when I click it appears for split second and becomes black\instantly becomes black.

Comment: Call resume() and pause() methods of the surface view from onResume() and onPause() methods of the MainActivity

Comment: could you show how to do it? I'm not very good with surfaceview, its my first time using it

Comment: there is no .resume() or .pause() on surfaceview